# What is the most reliable way to compare two FieldInfo instances?

Tags: c#, reflection

I don't mean the values.

I had a case where two instances of `FieldInfo` were not equalling and the cause ended up being that they were simply reflected through different types even though the declaring type on both was the same. And the name was the same.

So I came up with:

```cs
fi1.DeclaringType == fi2.DeclaringType && fi1.Name == fi2.Name
```

But is that the best way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will depend on what you deem to be the definition of equality in this case. If you are happy for it to only be declaring type and name then what you have is fine

Comment: Well, it's in a validation routine to flag fields that have a problem, so the field is definitely the same one but my validation has to use a base class. Maybe I should have asked how to obtain the fieldinfo on the base class huh.